# Fourier series of a non-periodic function possible?

Tags: fourier-series, periodic-functions

I have read online that Fourier series are only applicable to periodic functions. Ive included the following example in my work however it is not a periodic function, does this mean that the following calculation is incorrect?

Consider the function $f(x)=x-\pi$, then the following Fourier coefficients over the region$[0,2\pi]$ are:
$a_0={}\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{2\pi}_{0}f(x)\,dx \hspace{1em}\,
={} \frac{1}{\pi}\int^{2\pi}_{0}(x-\pi)\,dx 
={} \frac{1}{\pi}\left[\frac{1}{2}x^2-\pi x\right]^{2\pi_{0}}
={}\frac{1}{\pi}(2\pi^2-2\pi^2)
={}0\\
a_n={}\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{2\pi}_{0}\cos(nx)(x-\pi)\,dx
={}\frac{1}{\pi}\left[\frac{\sin(nx)(x-\pi)}{n}\right]^{2\pi}_{0}-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}\,dx ={}\frac{1}{\pi}\left[\frac{-cos(nx)}{n2}\right]^{2\pi}_{0}
={}0\\
b_n={}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(x)(x-\pi)\,dx
={}\frac{1}{\pi}\left[\frac{-cos(x)(x-\pi)}{n}\right]^{2\pi}_{0}+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}
={}\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{-\pi}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)
={}-\frac{2}{n}$
Giving Fourier series $x-\pi =-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n}\sin(nx)$

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 2):

Since you have limited the function to the region $[0,2\pi)$, you've basically stated that the period is $2\pi$. The resulting Fourier series will simply repeat itself on the intervals $[0,2\pi)$, $[2\pi,4\pi)$, $[4\pi,6\pi)$, and so on.

Try plotting the resulting Fourier series for a large number of terms. You will see a periodic "saw" pattern emerge. **What you calculated is the Fourier series of that periodic saw function.**

But of course, you can restrict yourself to the interval $[0,2\pi]$ afterwards if you want. There is nothing wrong with that.

Edit: To answer the question more directly, no, taking the Fourier series of a non-periodic function is not strictly speaking possible. To treat non-periodic functions, you need to use an integral Fourier transform, which you can think of as a Fourier series with an infinite period.

Comment: Does this mean that the Fourier series over any $2\pi$ interval of a non-periodic function will converge in the same interval? So for any bounded function $[-a,a]$ I can find the Fourier series for that interval by considering coefficients of the form $a_n={}\frac{1}{a}\int^{a}_{-a}\cos(\frac{nx\pi}{a})f(x)\,dx$ and likewise for $b_n$?

Comment: Yes, you can always do that for any non-periodic function in a bounded interval (provided that the coefficients exist of course). That basically makes the function periodic on $[-a,a]$ by assumption.

But note that there is subtlety with convergence at the boundaries when the function is discontinuous like in your case. You will notice that the series does not converge uniformly to the target function. To approximate the function well close to the discontinuity, you need to add a lot of terms. Just one thing to notice.

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier series converges to $x-\pi$ on the interval $(0,2\pi)$, and of course to $0$ at $x=0$.  Outside that interval it converges to the function made periodic, so
$f(x+2\pi k) = x - \pi$ for $0 < x < 2\pi$ and integers $k$.